# Incorrect Syntax near the keyword On

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to make a query at work in which I count all occurrences of an id in one table and then I link the description and the colors associated with those ids from another.

But I seem to have botched up my SQL Syntax (it's been a while, sorry!). It's probably just a silly mistake and I'd be so greatful to whoever could help me out!

```
SELECT 
    t1.activity_status_id,
    count(*),
    t2.description,
    t2.color
FROM
    dbo.Activity t1
INNER JOIN (
    dbo.Activity_Status t2 ON t1.activity_status_id = t2.id)
GROUP BY
    activity_status_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT t1.activity_status_id,
       Count(*),
       t2.description,
       t2.color
FROM   dbo.Activity t1
       INNER JOIN dbo.Activity_Status t2
               ON t1.activity_status_id = t2.id
GROUP  BY t1.activity_status_id ,t2.description,t2.color
```

Comment: When I do that I get the error: `Column 'dbo.Activity_Status.description' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Okay that worked. It seems that grouping was the issue there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just remove unnecessary brackets `(` and `)` around inner join:

```
SELECT ....
FROM
    dbo.Activity t1
    INNER JOIN dbo.Activity_Status t2 ON t1.activity_status_id = t2.id
GROUP BY ....
```

Comment: @Vipar That's truly reasonable since you're neither grouping by this column nor applying any  aggregate function on it - so it can't "directly" present in select list. Same story with `color` column - you have to either group by it or apply aggregate function on it.